# Rebuild web index option disappeared on disabling Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.Index.Web.config in CMS

Tags: sitecore-client

I am using SOLR search provider with Sitecore 8.2 Update 1. I have separate sites for CMS and CDE. As per the the [documentation](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/xdb/configuring_servers/configure_a_content_management_server), I should disable `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.Index.Web.config` file in CMS. If I remove this file, it is not showing the check box to select rebuild web index from the control panel. It will leave me dependent on the the publishing to get web index updated.

How to resolve this issue where I am not able to rebuild the web index at all?

Another point is, I want to index selective nodes of content tree in web index. Configuration for that exist in `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.Index.Web.config`.
In the absence of this file how publishing will decide that only selective nodes of content tree should index?

Comment: I would suggest to create a custom index file instead of using the Default Sitecore Web Index. Hence, you will be able to build the index from CM

Comment: @HishaamNamooya Are you suggesting to create a new index and use that for searching stuff and keep that enabled on both CMS and CDE?

Comment: Yes because your CM server have access to the CD server. Else the only way to rebuild the Web index would be to login on the CD server and perform the rebuild index there

Comment: @HishaamNamooya You caught it right. CMS and CDE are configured separately but we have same SOLR instance and same master and web databases for both sites.  Even if I create a new index I will be in same situation where I am with web index currently. As Sitecore suggests to disable the web index in CMS and Master index in CDE, are they expecting the rebuild of the indexing will happen from their respective sites. It means I will have to keep sitecore login enabled on CDE

Comment: Yes so, you can create a custom index for the web database with the strategy as onPublishEndAsync and then you can also rebuild it manually

Comment: If i still want to use web index, will i need to enable sitecore login on CDE?

Comment: Yes or you can let it as active on the CM server. It will not cause any issue

Comment: @HishaamNamooya I am also thinking of same now. Thanks for your view on this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on experience, I would suggest to create a custom index which is targeting your target database (ex: web). There is no need to disable the index config file.

Since your CM server has access to the web database, the only way to rebuild the web index is by not disabling it. From my point of view, there is no issues if the web index is enabled on CM.

If you disable the web index config file on the CM server, the only way to rebuild the web index is by login into the CD server and rebuild it.